# c# windows forms, load first google image in app itself

Tags: c#, image, display

I am wondering, if its possible to display the first image of google picture search in the visual studio windows form.

The way I imagine this would work, is that a person enters a string, then the app googles the string, copies the first image, and then displays it in the app itself.

Thank you.

EDIT: Please consider, that I am a beginner in C# programming, so if you are going to use some difficult coding or suggest to use some APIs, could you please explain in more detail how to do so, thank you.

Comment: Please read [Help Center > Asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Do some research, try stuff ... and if you are stuck, come back and present the question about where you stuck at.

Comment: Ive been trying to figure out how to do so for the past two hours, there is no harm in asking for help. It is not like I just realized I need this, and instead of trying to figure it out myself instantly asked for help here.

Comment: [C# – How to use Google Custom Search API?](http://hintdesk.com/c-how-to-use-google-custom-search-api/)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, Yes.

We know the URL to get an image is

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=plane&tbm=isch&site=imghp

On the Form create a PictureBox(Call it pbImage), a TextBox(Call it tbSearch), a Button(Call it btnLookup).

Using the Nuget Package Manager (Tools-> Nuget.. -> Manage..), select browse and search for **HtmlAgilityPack**. Click the your project on the right and then click install.

When we send a request to google using **System.Net.WebClient** there is no javascript being executed (however this can be done by some trickery with the winforms web browser).

As there is no javascript the page will be rendered differently to what you are used to. Inspecting the page without javascript tells us the following flow of the page:

1. Within the document body a **table** with a class called 'images_table'

   - Within that we can find several **img** elements.

Here is a code listing:

```
 private void btnLookup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string templateUrl = @"https://www.google.co.uk/search?q={0}&tbm=isch&site=imghp";

        //check that we have a term to search for.
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbSearch.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please supply a search term"); return;
        }
        else
        {
            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                //lets pretend we are IE8 on Vista.
                wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0)");
                string result = wc.DownloadString(String.Format(templateUrl, new object[] { tbSearch.Text }));

                //we have valid markup, this will change from time to time as google updates.
                if (result.Contains("images_table"))
                {
                    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                    doc.LoadHtml(result);

                    //lets create a linq query to find all the img's stored in that images_table class.
                    /*
                     * Essentially we get search for the table called images_table, and then get all images that have a valid src containing images?
                     * which is the string used by google
                    eg  https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQmGxh15UUyzV_HGuGZXUxxnnc6LuqLMgHR9ssUu1uRwy0Oab9OeK1wCw
                     */

                    var imgList = from tables in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("table")
                               from img in tables.Descendants("img")
                               where tables.Attributes["class"] != null && tables.Attributes["class"].Value == "images_table"
                               && img.Attributes["src"] != null && img.Attributes["src"].Value.Contains("images?")
                               select img;



                   byte[] downloadedData =  wc.DownloadData(imgList.First().Attributes["src"].Value);

                    if (downloadedData != null)
                    {
                        //store the downloaded data in to a stream
                        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(downloadedData, 0, downloadedData.Length);

                        //write to that stream the byte array
                        ms.Write(downloadedData, 0, downloadedData.Length);

                        //load an image from that stream.
                        pbImage.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Using **System.Net.WebClient** a request is sent to google using the url specified in the template string.

Adding headers makes the request looks more genuine. WebClient is used to download the markup, this is stored in result.

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument create a document object, we then load the data that was stored in result.

A Linq query is obtains the img elements, taking the first in that list we download the data and store it in a byte array.

With that data a memory stream is created (this should be encapsulated in a using().)

Write the data into the memory stream, then load that stream into the picture boxes image.

Comment: Thank you, this was a perfect reply. Though I do have one question - the image it gets is the one from the thumbnail in the image table, therefore the size of it is very small, and stretching it produces a very low quality image. Is there a way to get the image after you press on it?

Comment: Yes, though there are going to be problems associated to doing this.

Comment: My previous comment ended before i finished typing it... but essentially those problems are two fold, when you click on the 'view image' button in google some websites use referral headers and things to stop you going straight to the image and instead you go straight to the page.

You will also need to do this using the form WebBrowser and keep checking if the WebBrowser has finished everything it needs to do then extract the larger image. (I don't have the syntax to hand)

Basically, yes you can do it and no you shouldn't because it won't be reliable.